# Cassandra not working after upgrade Ubuntu to 20.04

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh, ubuntu-20.04

Cassandra.service is running but couldn't be connected. Cqlsh also not working

Comment: I've installed Cassandra inside docker and it works good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cqlsh` doesn't work because Ubuntu 20.04 has [Python 3 installed by default](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes#Python3_by_default), and there is no release of `cqlsh` that supports it.  You need to install Python 2 to use `cqlsh`

Cassandra requires Java 8 - check that you have OpenJDK 8 installed (by default Java 11 is installed), and that Cassandra is configured to use it.

P.S. These problems with versions will be fixed with release of the Cassandra 4.0